# What do you call a book that is in your hand?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am trying to find words to describe two distinct entities related to books, but I guess I am struggling because English is not my native language.

What do you call the concrete entity of a book, e.g., a book that I have in my hands vs. the conceptual entity of a book, e.g., the one that a publisher has in their catalog?

For example, in Portuguese we could call the conceptual book a "livro" and the physical entity an "exemplar" of this "livro".

I think I could call them "Book" and "Book copy" but it is not very satisfying, are there better words to describe those two entities?

Comment: Handbook? I dont think there is a noun for that. A book is just a book. Your copy.

Comment: So how do you call the collective of all the copies of a book?

Comment: Edition,  it can be the first, the second. etc.  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/edition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent to your *exemplar* is *copy*, as Hachi says. *Book* is used of the conceptual entity and, in everyday conversation, of the physical item too. Isn't that the same in Portuguese? I know it is in French.

I'm a retired librarian, and we would order so many *copies* of a particular *title* from our book suppliers.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, in Portuguese is the same. The problem is just that I am trying to name entities in a database diagram and I wanted to find good distinct names for those two. But your example is perfect, that's exactly the kind of action I wanted to model.

Comment: We often refer to both as a "book" unless we have reason to stress which of them it is that we mean. (Mostly it is clear from the context - *There were three books lying on the table* versus *She has written a number of books on the subject*)  But as you indicate, we also use the term "a title" to indicate the non-substantial idea of a book. I am wondering if this might be another translation of *exemplar*. As you know this gets more complicated once digital books enter the conversation.

Comment: @WS2 I said in my answer that _book_ was used for the physical object in everyday language. I assume that _exemplar_ means _copy_ because I know that the French word _exemplaire_  does.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes - good thought about *exemplaire*. But you were also right when you pointed out that *livre* in French could also have the same conceptual meaning as *book* does in English.

Comment: Just a comment: _exemplar_ is the same as _exemplaire_ in French, but if we follow the strict definition of what the word _copy_ means, I am not sure they are completely equivalent to copies. They are more like particular instantiations of a parent entity, i.e., as Google's dictionary defines: "Exemplaire: Chacun des objets (surtout imprimés) reproduisant un type commun." I believe _copy_ would place the copied entity in the same semantic level as the copied source, whereas _exemplaire_ places it under it. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Cesar My Oxford Hachette dictionary translates the English noun *copy* as follows: 1. (reproduction, imitation) *copie f* 2.(edition) (of book, newspaper, report) *exemplaire m* (This is an abridgement and excludes such things as "certified copy"). However the French to English section translates *exemplaire* (livre, document) simply as "copy" - suggesting it is available for what we would call a "copy" one would make on a printer. Different people will clearly have their own ways of using these words - I don't think there is a hard and fast rule.

Comment: Complicating matters further, if I had a soft document and wanted to run of several hard ones from it, I might refer to them as "prints" rather than "copies".

Answer (score 2):

I think "a copy" or "a copy of [title]" is the best you are going to get.  If you went to the bookstore and asked to buy The Odyssey, it would be completely proper and expected to hear "let's see if we have a copy in stock".

I don't think you would hear someone say "let's see if we have a book copy".

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I should have added that I asked the question because am trying to name those entities in a concept diagram, but I am not expecting to hear anyone making this distinction in an everyday conversation.